# How can I get the SQL of a PreparedStatement in SAP HANA

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement, hana

I would like to log the SQL binding to the prepared statement.  I'm using Java 8, JDBC driver. I'm using SAP hana DB. I  have seen several posts that has oracle and other DBs but not SAP Hana.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to trace this from a client side using JDBC you can simply use the JDBC trace for that. It clearly shows the prepare step and every binding that occurs.
You might want to check the [documentation](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/f2/bbb7fb4e1247f29e325f8b29226d16/content.htm?frameset=/en/1c/86038c05464d31a7dcae14f2d8a7dd/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/f3/5ec71c485e493aa20d0bd0e3bff06a/plain.htm&node_id=11&show_children=false) for details.